# Goolge Analytics IOS Session

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

if I terminate an app and open it again. It will use old session, or use new session if I open within 30 miniutes since I do action

Answer (score 0):

By default session timeout is 30 min. So the session will continue.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sessions